# asp.net 4 WebForms cannot access login page because of authorization rule

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a `default.aspx` page which i want to deny access to anonymous users and in the same folder (root folder) i have `Logon.aspx` which i obviously want anonymous users to access. I have tried the following as specified on [Microsoft's support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316871) but i get 401 when trying to access Logon.aspx:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".VISITAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
</location>
```

Does anyone have an idea of what i am missing? My other option is to write some code to handle this in the `Application_BeginRequest` event in the `global.asax` but was hoping to do things the way Microsoft tells me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i decided to do instead was to create a folder called admin which contained the entire application and left the logon in the root so the authorization rules only apply to the admin folder. Either Microsoft support is BS or i am missing something.

Note: If anyone out there stumbles across this thread in years to come i will be happy to give you credit for giving me a worthy answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started with .Net 4.x / Visual Studio 2015 (upgraded from VS2008) and ran into the same problem when I wanted to add a quick and simple authentication mechanism to a working web application. One of the things that caught my attention was the url rewrite: when entering "Login.aspx" the web address changed to "Login", without the .aspx extension, so I tried a few things and here's a solution:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".VISITAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Logon">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
</location>
```

The second location ("Logon") is a rewrite of the first one ("Logon.aspx") and thus needs the same authorization rules.

In hindsight, it seems logical to me that both paths need to be granted access. Perhaps it's unlogical though that it needs to be done *explicitly*, while the loginUrl of the forms authentication only mentions the original path.